# three parameter log normal distribution

Tags: math

It's so important to me.
do you know the three-parameter lognormal threshold formula?

I need to Excel solver function.
A probability distribution of outcomes that is symmetrical or forms a bell curve is called a normal distribution. A log-normal distribution can be formed from a normal distribution using logarithmic mathematics.

The error message indicates that there was a problem in estimating the gradient of the objective function. There are several reasons this could happen, but the most likely is that one of the parameters is becoming negative or causing negative values during the distribution fitting/optimization process

Thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome! I guess your question is more for https://stats.stackexchange.com/ dedicated to statistics

Comment: Many solvers behave quite bad with 3 varying parameters, especially if no good initial values are provided. You didn't show code nor test data, so this post is not a fit for StackOverflow. You could try to exponentiate your data, try to fit a normal distribution, and then take the log again.